# Authorisation testing by generate key in Jmeter - idea of test case

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, functional-testing, testcase

I'm testing authorisation in JMeter. Authorisation is by key, which is sent in `JSON.stringify`. First is open connected by web socket, next sent is key in JSON format.
Key is generated in the tool.

What test case could be? 
I think set happy path, and next authentication failed and in this give

1. missing key - what testing/set this in JMeter?
2. bad key - not exist

If is test case, that key not exist, it's worth additionaly create test case, that key is too long or too short, or wrongly sign?
What could be test case for this authorization?

Test case on input and output, e. g. no connection to the web socket connection? Are correctly?
I'm also thinking about test case, that JSON are wrong format or empty JSON lack JSON? It is correctly?
What could be addicted test case? What testing authentication in JMeter?

Comment: anyone help me?

Comment: The question is not suitable for SO format, and very hard to read. Try to create 1 question for each item and delete this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your test case will have only 2 types of expected result:

1. You're logged in (in case of "good" key)
2. You're not logged in (in case of "bad" key) - so called [Negative Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_testing)

My expectation is that you should be at least checking that the system doesn't let you in when you provide the wrong key, to wit "happy" and "unhappy" responses must be different.

Going forward you can check if unauthorised user doesn't have access to the parts of the application he should not be having access to.

Also if your application assumes [role-based access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) you should also check whether effective permissions of the user match his role (i.e. read-only users should not be able to create/update/delete stuff)

In the absolute majority of cases you can use [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to check presence/absence of a text/pattern in the response